# spawn multiple processes to write different files Python

Tags: python

The idea is to write `N` files using `N` processes.

The data for the file to be written are coming from multiple files which are stored on a dictionary that has a list as a value and it looks like this:

```
dic = {'file1':['data11.txt', 'data12.txt', ..., 'data1M.txt'],
       'file2':['data21.txt', 'data22.txt', ..., 'data2M.txt'], 
        ...
       'fileN':['dataN1.txt', 'dataN2.txt', ..., 'dataNM.txt']}
```

so `file1` is `data11 + data12 + ... + data1M` etc...

So my code looks like this:

```
jobs = []
for d in dic:
    outfile = str(d)+"_merged.txt"
    with open(outfile, 'w') as out:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target = merger.merger, args=(dic[d], name, out))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
        out.close()
```

and the merger.py looks like this:

```
def merger(files, name, outfile):
    time.sleep(2)
    sys.stdout.write("Merging %n...\n" % name)

    # the reason for this step is that all the different files have a header
    # but I only need the header from the first file.
    with open(files[0], 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            print "writing to outfile: ", name, line
            outfile.write(line) 
    for f in files[1:]:
        with open(f, 'r') as infile:
            next(infile) # skip first line
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
    sys.stdout.write("Done with: %s\n" % name)
```

I do see the file written on the folder it should go to, but it's empty. no header, no nothing. I had put prints in there to see if everything is correct but nothing works.

Help!

Comment: You call `out.close()` immediately after `p.start()`. I doubt the merge task has time to execute before the file is closed out from under it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard good point but still nothing...

Comment: This is on a linux like operating system, right?

Comment: @Blorgbeard closing the read-only file in the parent doesn't affect the file in the child. If there was written data to be flushed, that would be a problem, but that is not the case here.

Comment: @tdelaney the file opened/closed in the parent is a write-access file. I'm talking about `open(outfile, 'w')` and `out.close()`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard oops, you're right, it was writable. But since OP didn't write to it, its perfectly okay to close it. Closing in the parent doesn't close the child.

Comment: @Blorgbeard and tdelaney Thank you both for taking the time to review my question. Take a look at the answer I approved. Alex Hall summarized everything very well

Comment: @Pavlos - but its not correct. Didn't you also change your code to close the file in the child (either explicitly or via a `with` clause)? That's what fixed the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney ah, I see what you mean. I was trying to test it, but I can't even write to the file in the child - I assume that's because I'm on windows.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I added an example in my answer below but only ran it on my linux machine. I'm curious what happens on Windows but don't have one with me at the moment. If you get a minute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the worker processes run in parallel to the main process creating them, the files named `out` get closed before the workers can write to them. This will happen even if you remove `out.close()` because of the `with` statement. Rather pass each process the filename and let the process open and close the file.

Comment: @Pavlos no, keep the same number of processes, but just pass filenames instead of file objects.

Comment: But closing the file in the parent shouldn't be a problem for the child. I don't see how this fixed it!

Comment: @tdelaney because the parent closed the file before the child had a chance to write to it, and once a file is closed you can't write to it.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. The child is spawned with an independent copy of the file descriptor. The parent can close its version but that makes no difference to the child. What really happened here was that OP didn't close the file in the child so its unwritten data was discarded. When OP changed to open the file in the child he also changed to close it in the child. That's what really fixed the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney I think you're right, I forgot that processes get separate copies.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't close the file in the child so internally buffered data is lost. You could move the file open to the child or wrap the whole thing in a try/finally block to make sure the file closes. A potential advantage of opening in the parent is that you can handle file errors there. I'm not saying its compelling, just an option.

```
def merger(files, name, outfile):
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.stdout.write("Merging %n...\n" % name)

        # the reason for this step is that all the different files have a header
        # but I only need the header from the first file.
        with open(files[0], 'r') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                print "writing to outfile: ", name, line
                outfile.write(line) 
        for f in files[1:]:
            with open(f, 'r') as infile:
                next(infile) # skip first line
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)
        sys.stdout.write("Done with: %s\n" % name)
    finally:
        outfile.close()
```

**UPDATE**

There has been some confusion about parent/child file decriptors and what happens to files in the child. The underlying C library does not flush data to disk if a file is still open when the program exits. The theory is that a properly running program closes things before exit. Here is an example where the child loses data because it does not close the file.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time

if os.path.exists('mytestfile.txt'):
    os.remove('mytestfile.txt')

def worker(f, do_close=False):
    time.sleep(2)
    print('writing')
    f.write("this is data")
    if do_close:
        print("closing")
        f.close()


print('without close')
f = open('mytestfile.txt', 'w')
p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(f, False))
p.start()
f.close()
p.join()
print('file data:', open('mytestfile.txt').read())

print('with close')
os.remove('mytestfile.txt')
f = open('mytestfile.txt', 'w')
p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(f, True))
p.start()
f.close()
p.join()
print('file data:', open('mytestfile.txt').read())
```

I run it on linux and I get

```
without close
writing
file data: 
with close
writing
closing
file data: this is data
```

Comment: Here's what I get on Windows (python 2 and 3): http://pastebin.com/kwTAaT5t - tldr: errors.

Comment: Not unexpected. Windows tries to reopen the file but it's not open for sharing. Not wrong.... Just different.